# Is PyMySQL's fetchone() buffered?

Tags: pymysql

I am executing database queries which might result in thousands of rows.

The most simple way would to iterate over `fetchall()`:

```py
import pymysql

sql_command = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE some_condition;"
connection = pymysql.connect(...)
cursor = connection.cursor()
nof_affected_rows = cursor.execute(sql_command)
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    # process row
```

However, I am afraid of memory exhaustion here. Thus, another naive approach would be to iterate over `fetchone`, one element at a time.

```py
import pymysql

sql_command = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE some_condition;"
connection = pymysql.connect(...)
cursor = connection.cursor()
nof_affected_rows = cursor.execute(sql_command)
while True:
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    if not row:
        break
    # process row
```

Now a colleague argued I should use `fetchmany()` because it would retrieve multiple elements at once and thus would avoid roundtrips. At the same time I would stay in control of memory consumption.

Is that true? Is `fetchone()` buffered or not. If it is buffered, to which extend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyMySQL eagerly downloads all elements when executing the query.

Unfortunately, I was unable to find definite statements in the documentation. Therefore I conducted a small experiment.

I started IPython and executed the following code snippet:

```py
import pymysql

sql_command = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE some_condition;"
connection = pymysql.connect(...)
cursor = connection.cursor()
nof_affected_rows = cursor.execute(sql_command)
```

This resulted in approx. 450000 rows to load.

In a separate terminal, I monitored the memory consumption of IPython using `htop`. The memory consumption went up from 0.1% to 7.3% which corresponds to approx. 2.2GiB of memory.

*After* I disconnected from the network, I was still able to retrieve all elements from the Cursor.

Therefore I conclude that all rows are retrieved at `cursor.execute()`. Thus, in PyMySQL the question of whether to use `fetchone`, `fetchmany` or `fetchall` boils down to whatever is more convenient.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [SSCursor](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html#pymysql.cursors.SSCursor)

```py
cursor = connection.cursor(pymysql.cursors.SSCursor)
cursor.execute(sql_command)
for row in cursor:  # Cursor is iterable. You don't have to call `fetch*()` methods.
    # process row
```